# Tkinter doesn't respond to alt-release events sometimes

Tags: python, tkinter

Tkinter doesn't respond to alt-release events sometimes, which can be seen from the demo below.

```py
import tkinter

class ModeSwitcher:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.__tkCanvas = None

    def bind2Canvas(self,tkCanvas:tkinter.Canvas):
        self.__tkCanvas = tkCanvas
        # Single selection mode
        self.__tkCanvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Control_L>",self.__control_pressed_bindable,add=True)
        self.__tkCanvas.bind_all("<KeyRelease-Control_L>",self.__control_released_bindable,add=True)

        # Deselection mode
        self.__tkCanvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Alt_L>",self.__alt_pressed_bindable,add=True)
        self.__tkCanvas.bind_all("<KeyRelease-Alt_L>",self.__alt_released_bindable,add=True)
        self.__info_text = self.__tkCanvas.create_text(100,100,text="None")

    def __control_pressed_bindable(self,event):
        self.__tkCanvas.itemconfig(self.__info_text,text='control down')
    
    def __control_released_bindable(self,event):
        self.__tkCanvas.itemconfig(self.__info_text,text='control up')
    
    def __alt_pressed_bindable(self,event):
        self.__tkCanvas.itemconfig(self.__info_text,text='alt down')
    
    def __alt_released_bindable(self,event):
        self.__tkCanvas.itemconfig(self.__info_text,text='alt up')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tkWindow = tkinter.Tk()
    canvas_width = 600
    canvas_height = 600
    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(tkWindow,width = canvas_width, height = canvas_height)
    canvas.pack()

    mode_switcher = ModeSwitcher()
    mode_switcher.bind2Canvas(canvas)
    tkWindow.mainloop()
```

**NB**:

- The text is still `alt down` when the alt key is released, sometimes.
- But, the text refreshes after the GUI is clicked.

Comment: Try removing those `add=True` when binding.

Comment: Thank you. It works after those  `add=True` are removed.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour when you press the Alt-key, as you will (by default) navigate to the window's menu just like the default behaviour of your browser. There are no menus defined in your window so this is not visible to you, but your focus is leaving the canvas after which it is no longer updated until you click it or press a key.
Disable the default alt-key behaviour, or change it so that the focus does not leave the canvas.

I've added three lines before your `mainloop()`, which adds a menu bar to your canvas. This shows you what happens to your focus when you press Alt.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tkWindow = tkinter.Tk()
    canvas_width = 600
    canvas_height = 600
    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(tkWindow,width = canvas_width, height = canvas_height)
    canvas.pack()

    mode_switcher = ModeSwitcher()
    mode_switcher.bind2Canvas(canvas)
    
    menu = tkinter.Menu(canvas)
    menu.add_cascade(label="File")

    tkWindow.config(menu=menu)
    tkWindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's solved after those `add=True` when binding is removed.

The issue is caused by the inner function of the alt key (when it pressed,the software would show the shortcuts of menu items)

```py
import tkinter

class ModeSwitcher:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.__tkCanvas = None

    def bind2Canvas(self,tkCanvas:tkinter.Canvas):
        self.__tkCanvas = tkCanvas
        # Single selection mode
        self.__tkCanvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Control_L>",self.__control_pressed_bindable,add=True)
        self.__tkCanvas.bind_all("<KeyRelease-Control_L>",self.__control_released_bindable,add=True)

        # Deselection mode
        self.__tkCanvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Alt_L>",self.__alt_pressed_bindable)
        self.__tkCanvas.bind_all("<KeyRelease-Alt_L>",self.__alt_released_bindable)
        self.__info_text = self.__tkCanvas.create_text(100,100,text="None")

    def __control_pressed_bindable(self,event):
        self.__tkCanvas.itemconfig(self.__info_text,text='control down')
    
    def __control_released_bindable(self,event):
        self.__tkCanvas.itemconfig(self.__info_text,text='control up')
    
    def __alt_pressed_bindable(self,event):
        self.__tkCanvas.itemconfig(self.__info_text,text='alt down')
    
    def __alt_released_bindable(self,event):
        self.__tkCanvas.itemconfig(self.__info_text,text='alt up')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tkWindow = tkinter.Tk()
    canvas_width = 600
    canvas_height = 600
    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(tkWindow,width = canvas_width, height = canvas_height)
    canvas.pack()

    mode_switcher = ModeSwitcher()
    mode_switcher.bind2Canvas(canvas)
    tkWindow.mainloop()
```